# http api request with captured fingerprint data

Tags: python-2.7, flutter, touch-id, android-fingerprint-api

Am building a platform to replace making use of secret pins to authenticate user's permission. Would love to know how I can make Http request with captured fingerprint data in a flutter to return a response in updating a UI.

```
url = 'localhost/trix/sand_box/pay';

FingerData = User.ScannedPrint;

Future<Pay> async {
    Pay pay = await http.post(url: url, body = FingerData, header = 
              'application/json');
}
```

Comment: what is the TYPE of `FingerData` ??

Comment: which flutter plugin you are using for finger authentication ??

Comment: the database accepts the binary signature of the captured prints. Would like to return a response once it has found that such a user exists, like his/her id, name, pic or in my case approve a payment or return associated bank accounts connected to that print

Comment: can you tell me which plugin you are using on flutter ?? and what is the `TYPE` of `FingerData` ?? Please update your question.

Comment: about the plugin, I have no idea on what to use. I saw local_auth but its stating using captured prints from phone security. I don't want that approach as I can log in to a friend's app and still wanna perform such operation without getting an error message of prints not found.

Comment: well, what I think is you need to first finalize your approach from the mobile side. Then, only you can finalize how to handle things on the backend side.

Comment: what would be your recommendation for a plugin to use that allows free fingerprint capturing

Comment: well, according to me, there is only one plugin on flutter for this i.e. `local_auth`. either ask around in community or write your own plugin in native code for Android, iOS.